# Xbox Application Development

Tags: c#, xna, xbox360, xbox

I've been scouring the internet for a guide to creating an xbox application (not a game) but have been unsuccessful so far.  I've found that Microsoft provides XNA and XDK, and that the XDK is only available through their developer program.

Is doesnt seem like it is possible to create an application by just using the XNA, however, I am not sure if this is correct or not.  It does look like the XNA will allow you to create a game, but I'm not sure if this is the right development kit to use if youre only creating an application. So, can I use the XNA to create an xbox application or do I need to do something else for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have a Developers Licence. The App deploys to the Xbox directly to run/debug. The only way to register your Xbox with  your VS is to input the licence ID.